# Time series data storage

Tags: java, sockets, go, network-programming, time-series

I'm collecting a large number of UDP packets (time dependant) coming from a service on the same network. These packets are being deserialised into structures that contain numbers (float and int) in memory and processed. We could say we are collecting time series data. However, it's not the kind of time series data that you get from supervising a service (mostly the same value for a period of time). These values constantly vary, true, not by very much. But they vary, nevertheless.

Besides this, I would like to send that data to a server in the cloud and on that server store the time series data.

My question is: what possibilities are there to compress the data in order to send smaller packets over the wire to the server (we could send the incoming UDP packets in batches over TCP) and store them? I'm particularly interested in not using the whole storage I have attached to the server. The data for one session is close to 32MB and i would have multiple sessions at the same time. One session's data is not related to another session. They are totally independent.

Comment: You asked: "[W]hat possibilities are there to compress the data[?]" with the obvious answer: lzh, zip, gzip, compress whatever, choose any. Probably your question is a different one?

Comment: so you're basically reimplementing statsd and graphite? :)

Comment: Have a look at influxdb. It might be good fit for your usecase.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are asking about. Is the server where all data is stored developed by you as well? Is your primary goal to compress data for transfer or data stored at the server? If both of these goals are valid then you should probably use different schema for transfer and different for storage. But it depends on the kind of values. Are the values changing rapidly?

Comment: @FlorinDiaconeasa How long does the `session` last? How does 32MB of raw data translates into time-series, in terms of time+float sample count per second/minute.

Comment: Basically, they are random numbers. My question is related mostly to what compression algorithm provides better ratio for this kind of data.

Comment: @Sergei : I would get something around ~50 incoming udp packets per second, each around 1500B

Comment: Whatever algo you choose, you would get better compression ratio if you compress multiple packets at once, better the whole 35MB, regardless if this happens on the client (your app) or the server (tsdb). The load itself not that large, TSDBs are able to process 100K/s inserts easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can compress time series data using this library: https://github.com/dgryski/go-tsz

It's based on this paper from Facebook:
http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol8/p1816-teller.pdf

> We have found that about 96% of all time stamps
>   can be compressed to a single bit.
>
> [...]
>
> Roughly 51% of all values are compressed to a single bit since
>   the current and previous values are identical. About 30% of
>   the values are compressed with the control bits ‘10’ (case b),
>   with an average compressed size of 26.6 bits. The remaining
>   19% are compressed with control bits ‘11’, with an average
>   size of 36.9 bits, due to the extra 13 bits of overhead required
>   to encode the length of leading zero bits and meaningful bits.

You can use a key-value store like bolt (or probably better: rocksdb which supports compression) and store multiple points for each key. For example you could store one key-value pair every 10 minutes, where the value would be all of the points that occurred during that 10 minute window.

This should give you both good performance and high compression.

Comment: Unfortunately, i doesn't that distribution :) I've updated the question with the following: "We could say we are collecting time series data. However, it's not the kind of time series data that you get from supervising a service (mostly the same value for a period of time). These values constantly vary, true, not by very much. But they vary, nevertheless."